# How to show fields based on a condition for other field

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning, visualforce-component, conditional

I want to show 4 custom fields (W__c, X__c, Y__c, Z__c) when other custom field have the following condition:

If RealNumber__c < TargetNumber__c
then show this field:
W__c, X__c, Y__c, Z__c
else 
hide this field:
W__c, X__c, Y__c, Z__c

I am using the following APEX code in Visualforce Page, but it doesn't work for me:

```
<apex:page standardController="CustomObject__c">

<apex:form id="theForm">

  <apex:inputfield value="{!CustomObject__c.RealNumber__c}">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="theForm" />
</apex:inputField>

  <apex:inputField value="{!CustomObject__c.W__c}" rendered="{!CustomObject__c.RealNumber__c < !CustomObject__c.TargetNumber__c}" />
  <apex:inputField value="{!CustomObject__c.X__c}" rendered="{!CustomObject__c.RealNumber__c < !CustomObject__c.TargetNumber__c}" />
  <apex:inputField value="{!CustomObject__c.Y__c}" rendered="{!CustomObject__c.RealNumber__c < !CustomObject__c.TargetNumber__c}" />
  <apex:inputField value="{!CustomObject__c.Z__c}" rendered="{!CustomObject__c.RealNumber__c < !CustomObject__c.TargetNumber__c}" />


</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

David helped me and finally the code is:

```
<apex:page standardController="CustomObject__c">
<apex:form id="theForm">
 <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!CustomObject__c.RealNumber__c < CustomObject__c.TargetNumber__c}"> 
<apex:inputField value="{!CustomObject__c.W__c}"/> 
<apex:inputField value="{!CustomObject__c.X__c}"/> 
<apex:inputField value="{!CustomObject__c.Y__c}"/> 
<apex:inputField value="{!CustomObject__c.Z__c}"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

But when I press the button "Preview" the screen shows me the following error:
The value 'null' is not valid for operator '<'
Error is in expression '{!CustomObject__c.RealNumber__c < CustomObject__c.TargetNumber__c}' in component  in page CustomObject__c

What could be the problem ?

Can you help me with this please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a syntax error in there:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!CustomObject__c.W__c}" rendered="{!CustomObject__c.RealNumber__c < !CustomObject__c.TargetNumber__c}" />
```

should be

```
<apex:inputField value="{!CustomObject__c.W__c}" rendered="{!CustomObject__c.RealNumber__c < CustomObject__c.TargetNumber__c}" />
```

Once you're in the expression context, the `!` becomes a negation operation. You don't need to and shouldn't prefix each variable reference with that character; you just need it once to mark the beginning of the expression.

There's also a way you can simplify this: use an `<apex:outputPanel>` (a `<div>`, essentially) to group the elements, and conditionally render it:

```xml
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!CustomObject__c.RealNumber__c < CustomObject__c.TargetNumber__c}">
    <apex:inputField value="{!CustomObject__c.W__c}" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!CustomObject__c.X__c}" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!CustomObject__c.Y__c}" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!CustomObject__c.Z__c}" />
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Please also be aware, just for clarity's sake, that none of this is Apex code - it's Visualforce markup. Your controller is written in Apex, if you have a controller.

### `null` Issue

Your Visualforce expression is not valid because one of the fields `CustomObject__c.RealNumber__c < CustomObject__c.TargetNumber__c` is `null`. You cannot compare `null` to an integer value.

You'll need to either make sure the data is valid by populating fields, or enhance your logic to take `null` into account. You'd do this, for example, by wrapping each field in the [`BLANKVALUE()`](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=5) formula function, which allows you to substitute a value for `null`. (See the linked reference for usage details).

Comment: I fix the code and now can I save it, but now the screen shows me a error message when I click on "Preview" in Visualforce Page, please see the detail in the first question edited. Thanks for your support David

Comment: Now It works! Thank you so much for be patient. Regards